# What is the source of "Bootha hitha yathartha bashanameva satyam"?

Tags: identification-request, upanishads

In which context of which Upanishad, the following statement is present?

> **Bootha hitha yathartha bashanameva satyam**

Provide reference, if available.

Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XsNd_p3FOLc#t=2h48m22s) for a minute for more details (in Telugu language).

Comment: I don't think that is within the context of Upanishad.